# Send parameters to Cloud Functions with Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm using two firebase services : Cloud Functions & Firebase hosting.
According to the documentation I'm able to configure urls on Firebase hosting by using firebase.json :

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "public",
        "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "rewrites": [
            {
                "source": "**",
                "function": "showWebProduct"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So, in my case when anything is used on path URL it executes `showWebProduct`, but is it possible to send parameters to this Cloud function ? I don't fond any ressource which show an example with parameter in query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to specify parameters in the Hosting configuration to be included in the call to your function.  Instead, you should direct Hosting to a function that already has everything it needs to operate.

If you have a specific use case that demands it, you should [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: Sadly, I need a parameter to operates as planned. Thanks for your answer